# implementing get/set property in a concrete class which inherits from an abstract class

Tags: matlab, class, oop, abstract-class, getter-setter

I am trying to do the following in MATLAB:

define a super-class with property `a`:

```
classdef (Abstract) superClass 
     properties (Abstract = true)
          a;
     end
end
```

define a sub-class which inherits from super-class and implements a get function for `a`

```
classdef subClass < superClass
    methods
           function val = get.a(obj)
                val = obj.a;
           end
    end
    properties
        a;
    end
end
```

What I get is:

> Error using subClass
>   Error: File: subClass.m Line: 3 Column: 28
>   Cannot specify a get function for property 'a' in class 'subClass', because that      property is not defined by that class.

According to the documentation it suppose to be ok to define get/set on abstract properties.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://goo.gl/EGS8De) thread. They seem to discuss this issue and possible workarounds about it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I got it to work by simply defining the `properties` block **before** the `methods` block in the subclass (the order seems to matter here):

```
classdef subClass < superClass
    properties
        a;
    end
    methods
        function val = get.a(obj)
            val = obj.a;
        end
    end
end
```

I think this is an issue with the MATLAB parser, perhaps you should file a [bug report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/).